# Prove that $4^{n}-1$ is divided by $3^{k}$ if and only if $n=3^{k-1}t$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am aware that $3$ always divides $2^{2n}-1$, which is easy to prove. To deal with some automorphism groups, I am trying to generalise this to find the highest power of $3$ that can divide $2^n -1$.

A reasonable conjecture is that $2^{2n}-1$ is divided by $3^k$ if and only if $n=3^{k-1}m$. An example would be that $4^{3n+t} = 1 \mod 9$ if and only if $t=0$ (where, of course, $0 \leq t \leq 5$). This is easily proved by showing $2^{6n+t} \neq 1 \mod 9$ when $t \neq 0$.

I can't, however, find an easy argument to show this for $4^n - 1$, since checking every value of $t$ separately is not a viable strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if the multiplicative order of $a$ mod $p^k$ is $r$ (where $p$ is prime and $a > 1$ is not divisible by $p$), then the order of $a$ mod $p^{k+1}$ divides $r p$.  However, in some cases it is just $r$.  I want to prove that doesn't happen in the case $p=3$, $a=2$.

Let $\nu_p(x)$ denote the highest exponent $k$ such that $p^k | x$.

Note that $a^{3r} - 1 = (a^r-1)(a^{2r} + a^r + 1)$, so $\nu_3(a^{3r}-1) = \nu_3(a^r-1) + \nu_3(a^{2r} + a^r + 1)$.  If $a^r \equiv 1 \mod 3$, $a^{2r} + a^r + 1 \equiv 0 \mod 3$.  However, since $x^2 + x + 1 \equiv 0 \bmod 9$ has no solutions, it is not $0 \bmod 9$. Thus $\nu_3(a^{2r}+a^r+1) = 1$, and $\nu_3(a^{3r}-1) = \nu_3(a^r-1) + 1$.  By induction, $\nu_3(a^{3^k r}-1) = \nu_3(a^r-1) + k$.  Since $\nu_3(2^2-1) = \nu_3(3) = 1$, we have
$\nu_3(2^{2\cdot 3^k}-1) = k+1$.